# Literature/Book on counting processes

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-chains

I seek literature that makes a rigorous treatment of counting processes. In particular im interested in a precise treatment of the conditional intensity $\lambda_t$ which is often informally defined as

$$\lambda_tdt=P(N_t \text{ jumps in } [t,t+dt]\vert \mathcal{F}_t).$$

Comment: You can try looking for older literature on point processes (more recently point processes mostly mean random point fields), see if this helps